# Object reference

Tags: php, oop

In PHP, I have this simple class

```
<?php
class Person {
    var $first_name = "factory method";
}
?>
```

The question I have is if I have:

```
$person1 = new Person();
$person2 = $person1;

$person1 = null;

var_dump($person1);
var_dump($person2);
```

what I get is: both **$person1 = null** and **$person2 is not null at all**, it seems $person1 and $person2 are not pointing to the same thing at all.

but when I do something like below:

```
$person1 = new Person();
$person2 = $person1;
$person2->first_name = "programming";

echo $person1->first_name;
echo $person2->first_name;
```

I got the same thing "programming", so I think the both $person1 and $person2 are pointing to the same thing.

Could someone explain to me why is it like that?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Dont mix pointers with references. After `$person1 = null;` this variable refers to something different, because you assign something different to the variable. With

```
$person1 = $person2 = new Person;
```

Both refers the same single object instance. With `$person2->first_name` you change this object, not the variable, that still refers to the object.

Answer (score 0):

After you set $person1 to null in the first example it is no longer referring to the Person object that you created, but $person2 still is.

In the second example both $person and $person2 refer to the same object.

See the PHP manual on [References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php).